# Read all key-value pairs of each object in array

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

Here's my JSON object:

```
{
    "resources":[
        {
            "Foo":0,
            "Bar":"",
            "Fiz":1
        },
        {
            "Foo":2,
            "Bar":"",
            "Fiz":3
        }
    ]
}
```

The above JSON array `resources` is correctly detected as an `array`. I want to iterate over each object in the array and add the `key:value` pairs to a `map`.

It does detect the amount of objects (here: 2) correctly.
But how to iterate over the objects members? There comes an assertion that each element in the array is not an object. I do not understand, why!

Here's my code:

```
if ( jsonvalue->IsArray() ){ // that jsonvalue is my "resources" array
    for (rapidjson::SizeType i = 0; i < jsonvalue->Size(); i++){
        const rapidjson::Value& c = jsonvalue[i];
        // Is no object! assertion triggers in next call.
        for (rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator iter = c.MemberBegin(); iter != c.MemberEnd(); ++iter){
            printf("%s\t", iter->name.GetString());
            printf("%s\t", iter->value.GetString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating all values as `string` but in your JSON there are keys having value of `Int` type. So, you need to first check the type of each `value` before printing it.

Here's an example:

```
printf( "%s\t", iter->name.GetString() );

if ( iter->value.IsInt() )
{
    printf( "%d\t", iter->value.GetInt() );
}
else if ( iter->value.IsString() )
{
    printf( "%s\t", iter->value.GetString() );
}
```

I wonder why you are not using C++11 range-based for loop for iterations. RapidJSON has support for this. See [Example](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/blob/master/doc/tutorial.md#range-based-for-loop-new-in-v110).

Your code will be more readable and compact.